# I am trying to print the 301 status for scrapy requests. But, the page redirects and shows 200 everytime

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to print the 301 status for scrapy requests. But, the page redirects and I get 200 status code every time. I do not want the redirection to happen and just print the 301 code. I am new to Scrapy and can not figure it out.

I have the following code:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Uyn3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [meta](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta) attribute in your request, and you pass the key:value

- 'dont_redirect':'True
- 'handle_httpstatus_list': [301]

---

```
class RedirectSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'redirect'
url = 'http://www.wayfair.com/outdoor/sb0/fire-pits-c215964.html/'

def start_requests(self):
    yield scrapy.Request(
        url=self.url,
        meta={'dont_redirect': True, 'handle_httpstatus_list': [301]},
        callback=self.parse,
    )

def parse(self, response):
    print(response.status)
```